# Knockout custom binding in foreach to get iterator

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to make a custom binding that is to be used within a foreach binding and would need access to the current `observableArray` and the `$data`.

Now I notice the `bindingContext` arg contains the `$data, $parent, $root` etc however I cannot seem to find a way to access the array being iterated, so is there a way?

Just to be clear here is a sort of example of what I mean:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: People">
   <button data-bind="customBinding: someArg">DoSomethingWithArrayAndElement</button>
</div>
```

In this instance `customBinding` seems to yield:

- $data = current element in iteration
- $parent = view model containing the `People` array
- root = same as $parent
- $index = current index in the iterating array
- $parents = array containing the view model

Comment: You might have to attack that from a different angle. What's your custom binding supposed to do that it needs the array?

Comment: I have a lot of duplicated code within various view models which do some adding/removal with some other common logic, so I was looking at trying to improve some of this re-use by moving the common things to custom bindings (as the logic is the same in each instance). So its just me trying to reduce code to maintain.

Comment: if you are looking to access the array which is being currently iterated cant you just simply use `viewModel.people()` in custombindings . viewModel gives what you need . cheers

Comment: Viewmodel is being deprecated in custom bindings, also its not really any more re-useable as you would then have to make a binding per type, or make sure they all have the same variable name.

Comment: that is thoughtful . you sure `viewModel` is depreciated still i find that in doc's ? thanks

Comment: "viewModel — This parameter is deprecated in Knockout 3.x. Use bindingContext.$data or bindingContext.$rawData to access the view model instead." - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the way to go, but without further knowledge about your app it's the only thing I can suggest: make a custom `foreach` binding that exposes the full array.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.customForeach = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var newBindingContext = bindingContext.extend({iterator: valueAccessor()});

      return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, newBindingContext);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var newBindingContext = bindingContext.extend({iterator: valueAccessor()});

      return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, newBindingContext);
    }
  };

var ViewModel = function ViewModel() {
  this.items = ko.observableArray(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
  };

ko.applyBindings( new ViewModel() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="customForeach: items">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

This adds a new `iterator` property to your bindingContext, exposing the full array from inside it.

Comment: thanks for the example I will think about if it is really worth me adding this sort of approach in just to save a few lines of duplication, although currently its duplicated about 20 times. In most cases the crucial logic is as little as just removing the current element from the active array and firing an event (through an event system). So if we were to just think of this as a shortcut for removing an entry from an array without having to have any viewmodel functions, that is the crux of what these shortcut bindings would do.

Comment: That's what I meant - it feels like a kludge, and there is probably a better way. Maybe make a new question that focuses on "how can I remove de-duplicate this code"?

Comment: I strongly distinguish between 'viewmodels' - objects that hold the functions that can be executed through the UI - and data models. In my apps, "remove this array entry" in a `foreach` is usually just `click: $parent.removeItem.bind($parent, $data)`, `$parent` being the viewmodel that has `function removeItem(item) { this.items.remove(item); }`.

Comment: well all roads will lead to putting the logic in a view model, be it via some inheritance or enrichment of an instance, or just directly in there as it currently does, or put it in a custom binding. As way I see it anything that is not really business logic, and is just a simple repeatable action it is more reusable and easier to manage as a custom binding as it does not need peppering through all the source code, a lot like how you would use AOP style techniques to move cross cutting concerns out of the business logic code.

Comment: I see what you mean. One of my few issues with Knockout is that I find bindings harder to manage properly, in terms of namespacing, composition etc. For view- and data models on the other hand I have developed a pretty decent structure over the years. This is why I tend to favor them over bindings when possible.

Comment: I only really tend to use bindings currently to express behaviour (modal, tabs, file uploading etc) however after reading some articles it seemed like custom bindings could also be a candidate for housing project level re-usable logic. Like you say currently I do the `removeItem` method, and call that via a `click` binding, but really I can shortcut this to just a single binding without cluttering various view models, which is what is currently annoying me. I also have the notion of data models which are basically observable POJO style objects, consumed via composition in view models.

Answer (score 2):

So your goal is to make the underlying array accessible within the `foreach` template?  If you asked me, you *shouldn't* model your code in that way.

With that said, all you really need is an alias to your array and make sure you set the alias when you use the `foreach` binding.  Naturally, there's many ways you can do this.

Probably the cleanest way would be to create an `alias` binding handler.  Then extend the existing `foreach` binding to add the aliases or create a new one.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.alias = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var aliasValue = value.data;
            aliasName = value.aliasName || '$alias';
        if (ko.isObservable(aliasValue)) {
            var rawValue = aliasValue,
                rawAliasName = value.rawAliasName || '$rawAlias';
            bindingContext[rawAliasName] = rawValue;
            aliasValue = rawValue();
        }
        bindingContext[aliasName] = aliasValue;
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachex = {
    preprocess: function (value, name, addBinding) {
        addBinding('alias', "{ data: "+value+", aliasName: '$source', rawAliasName: '$rawSource' }");
        addBinding('foreach', value);
    }
};
```

Then you can just use the aliases in your view.

```
<div data-bind="foreachex: People">
    <!-- $rawSource is the People observable array -->
    <button data-bind="customBinding: someFunction($rawSource, $data)">
        DoSomethingWithArrayAndElement
    </button>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/ab7qer7u/)

Comment: It turns out there is already an open request for some similar functionality to be added to knockout: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/662 to allow for the use case mentioned. However you already have access to the `$index` within the foreach scope so I do not see why having access to the iterator is a bad thing, it just allows contextual shortcut bindings.